# On ubuntu 14.04 how do you check if TRIM is on for an SSD drive

Tags: 14.04, trim

On ubuntu 14.04 how do you check if TRIM is on for an SSD drive?
Other settings worth verifying for an SSD drive?

Answer (score 15):

To see the details for your weekly cron jobs, change directory to `/etc/cron.weekly` or include it in the command as below:

```
more /etc/cron.weekly/fstrim
```

You should see an output which looks something like:

```
#!/bin/sh
# trim all mounted file systems which support it
/sbin/fstrim --all || true
```

If this is present trim is active/checked and executed once a week. The help on this command will show you...

```
fstrim --help

Usage:
 fstrim [options] <mount point>

Options:
 -a, --all           trim all mounted filesystems that are supported
 -o, --offset <num>  the offset in bytes to start discarding from
 -l, --length <num>  the number of bytes to discard
 -m, --minimum <num> the minimum extent length to discard
 -v, --verbose       print number of discarded bytes

 -h, --help     display this help and exit
 -V, --version  output version information and exit
```

---

To see if trim is supported (change sda if you have more than 1 disks):

```
sudo hdparm -I /dev/sda | grep "TRIM supported"
```

and it should show something similar to this:

```
*   Data Set Management TRIM supported (limit 8 blocks)
```

Comment: FWIW, this works as shown in Ubuntu 15.04 as well.

Comment: I read somewhere that this trim option is supported only on Samsung and Intel SSDs?  Is this true?

Comment: @LjiljanVeselinovic those at least. But others do too. My OCZ works as well for instance,

Comment: I bought Trascent 370S. Trim is supported. Is Ubuntu 16.04 going to perform this job periodically?

Comment: yes once a week (see cron.weekly ;) )

Comment: This works in Ubuntu 16.04 as well. You can test it manually with `sudo /sbin/fstrim --all || true` and on my system the SSD/HDD indicator light was solid and bright for a few minutes.