# Trim supports for Kington SSD is in default or not?

Tags: ssd, trim

I have just installed Ubuntu 17.10 on a Kington SSD.

I heard that Ubuntu enables Trim by default, but it is only for some brands like Intel and Samsung while Sandisk and Kingston are not included in the list ([source](http://www.webupd8.org/2013/12/trim-enabled-by-default-for-ssds-on.html)).

Thus, I want to ask:

1. How do I check Trim was enabled for the SSD brands I am using (Kington and Sandisk)?
2. How do I enable if the trim is disabled?

**Update:**

Main question I want to ask you is Kington is not in supported list of fstrim, 
[And I have already read some old threads at here and somewhere at here that, enable Trim ubuntu only effect to supported brands (samsung, Intel)]

=> How to check/ enable/ disable Trim function for Kington SSD (special brand, which is not in the support list)

Because the old threads I read is maybe outdate.

**Update 2**: Kington technical supporter informed me that no need to care about Trim function in OS, because Garbage collection is a function was built-in firmware of Kington SSD.

Best regard,

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Check this answer : https://askubuntu.com/questions/572240/on-ubuntu-14-04-how-do-you-check-if-trim-is-on-for-an-ssd-drive

Comment: Both trim duplicate answers already answer that question generically, not specific to your Kingston hardware...  If we answer too specifically for specific hardware on this site, the questions and answers will not be relevant to other users and there might be no one around here with a Kingston SSD...